# Module pexpect truncate output

Tags: python, pexpect

I have simple code

```
cursor = pexpect.spawn(<some_command>)
cursor.expect(XXX)
cursor.sendline(<some_command>)
output = cursors.after
```

But in output not all text that i need, it's cut off (about 32 kb)
How i can get all text? It's about 50 kb

### Not a very good solution, but it works:

```
try:
    t = list()
    cursor.maxread = 1
    cursor.timeout = 15
    cursor.sendline('show lldp remote_ports')
    for line in cursor:
        t.append(line)
except Exception:
    cursor.delaybeforesend = 0.5
    cursor.maxread = 2000
    cursor.timeout = 180
```

Comment: what OS are you using?

Comment: debian wheezy (7.8), python 2.7

Comment: How are you judging how much text is returned?

Comment: I do the same command manually, and the script, and then compare them.